# Tricky Asymptotic Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\delta > 2$ be given. Does there exist an $N_0(\delta)$ and a $C(\delta)$ such that 
$$
C(\delta)t(\ln \ln t)^2 + t + N^{\delta} > (t+N^{\delta}) (\ln \ln t)
$$
for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $N^{\delta} \geq t \geq N \geq N_{0}(\delta)$?

Comment: If $\delta = 3$ and $t = N$ then the right hand side is asymptotic to $N^3 \ln\ln N$ while the left hand side is asymptotic to $N^3$ as $N \to \infty$, so the right-hand side will eventually be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No.

When $N\to\infty$, for $t=N$, the LHS is equivalent to $N^\delta$ (this step uses the hypothesis that $\delta\gt1$) while the RHS is equivalent to $N^\delta\log\log N$. Thus, the inequality cannot hold, for any $\delta\gt1$.